# Не получается прочитать через i2c eeprom память m24sr04

Tags: c++, c

Пытаюсь прочитать через i2c eeprom память m24sr04 (Dynamic NFC/RFID tag IC with 4-Kbit EEPROM).
Предварительно записал в тэг с помощью NFC некоторую информацию. И могу эту же информацию считать с помощью NFC.
Данная программа корректно читает вторую eeprom в которую записаны настройки платы (плата на основе PowerPC, Linux), но при считывании eeprom m24sr04 выводит множество "255" (при %d) или множество квадратиков (при %c).
Может кто знает в чем моя ошибка и как поступить в данной ситуации?

```
int main () {
    int file;
    char filename[40];
    const char *buffer;
    int addr = 0x2d;        // The I2C address of the ADC

    sprintf(filename, "/dev/i2c-0");
    if ((file = open(filename, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open the bus.");
        /* ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong */
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Success open the bus.\n");
    }

    if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to acquire bus access and/or talk to slave.\n");
        /* ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong */
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Managed to access the bus and / or talk to the slave\n");
    }


    /// Read
    unsigned char buf1[10000] = {0};
    int buf2[10000] = {0};


    if (read(file, buf1, 1000) != 1000) {
        /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
        printf("Failed to read from the i2c bus.\n");
        buffer = strerror(errno);
        cout << buffer << endl;
        printf("\n\n");
    } else {
        for(int j = 0; j<1000; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", buf1[j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите первый ответ: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkfSXSAZ/m24sr04-eeprom-direct-access

Comment: Если это про Linux, то поставьте соответствующий драйвер.